# Rails CanCan: reference to resource_instance from application_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have a bunch of controllers that extend the `ApplicationController` and each one loads a different cancan resource, e.g. `UsersController` -> `@user`, `PostsController` -> `@post`. I was wondering, is it possible to reference the resource from the ApplicationController without knowing the instance variable name? Something like `resource_instance`.

Comment: What's the code you want to put in your ApplicationController? This has nothing to do with `cancan`. Have you seen [inherited_resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources), its `resource`  it's closer to what you want.

Comment: @Leito After loading a resource, I set another instance variable depending on that resource (e.g. many of the resources have a company_id column, I'm setting `@company` depending on resource.company). I want to do this in ApplicationController so I don't have to duplicate the code. In pseudocode, I want the ApplicationController method to say: "Did cancan load a resource? If so, set `@company` depending on the resource.company"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got my final answer and it's **No**. I explored *cancancan*, *cancan*'s well maintained spiritual child and the code is there, but is not meant to be used by the end user.

You could get what you want, it isn't pretty:

```
self.class.cancan_resource_class.new(self).send(:resource_instance)
```

That said, please don't. `cancan_resource_class` isn't documented to to be used by end users and `:resource_instance` is protected, hence the `send`. The developers could choose to change this and break your application.

If all have a `company`, they belong too, I recommend you  nest the routes, so all routes have a `:company_id` you could use to get the `@company` object you want: `companies/:company_id/users`, etc.